# Elementary freezes after locking screen / Elementary 6.0 (PARTIALLY FIXED)

Tags: odin

I am using Elementary OS 6.
When I lock (WIN+L), it locks well and after a while, the lock screen get freezed.
It is not possible to input the password.
Yours

My PC Hardware : it is a ZBOX-IQ01-PLUS BE

if you want more: https://pastebin.com/9tt8gZ7t

My syslog :

```
Dec  4 09:56:52 ZBOXID92ZBOXIQ012691b898 io.elementary.a[2144]: hdy_carousel_box_get_position: assertion 'HDY_IS_CAROUSEL_BOX (self)' failed
Dec  4 09:56:52 ZBOXID92ZBOXIQ012691b898 io.elementary.a[2144]: hdy_carousel_box_get_n_pages: assertion 'HDY_IS_CAROUSEL_BOX (self)' failed
Dec  4 09:56:52 ZBOXID92ZBOXIQ012691b898 io.elementary.a[2144]: hdy_carousel_box_get_position: assertion 'HDY_IS_CAROUSEL_BOX (self)' failed
Dec  4 09:56:52 ZBOXID92ZBOXIQ012691b898 io.elementary.a[2144]: hdy_carousel_box_get_nth_child: assertion 'HDY_IS_CAROUSEL_BOX (self)' failed
Dec  4 09:56:52 ZBOXID92ZBOXIQ012691b898 io.elementary.a[2144]: hdy_carousel_box_scroll_to: assertion 'HDY_IS_CAROUSEL_BOX (self)' failed
Dec  4 09:56:57 ZBOXID92ZBOXIQ012691b898 io.elementary.a[2144]: hdy_carousel_box_get_position: assertion 'HDY_IS_CAROUSEL_BOX (self)' failed
Dec  4 09:56:57 ZBOXID92ZBOXIQ012691b898 io.elementary.a[2144]: hdy_carousel_box_get_n_pages: assertion 'HDY_IS_CAROUSEL_BOX (self)' failed
Dec  4 09:56:57 ZBOXID92ZBOXIQ012691b898 io.elementary.a[2144]: hdy_carousel_box_get_position: assertion 'HDY_IS_CAROUSEL_BOX (self)' failed
Dec  4 09:56:57 ZBOXID92ZBOXIQ012691b898 io.elementary.a[2144]: hdy_carousel_box_get_nth_child: assertion 'HDY_IS_CAROUSEL_BOX (self)' failed
Dec  4 09:56:57 ZBOXID92ZBOXIQ012691b898 io.elementary.a[2144]: hdy_carousel_box_scroll_to: assertion 'HDY_IS_CAROUSEL_BOX (self)' failed
Dec  4 09:57:02 ZBOXID92ZBOXIQ012691b898 io.elementary.a[2144]: hdy_carousel_box_get_position: assertion 'HDY_IS_CAROUSEL_BOX (self)' failed
Dec  4 09:57:02 ZBOXID92ZBOXIQ012691b898 io.elementary.a[2144]: hdy_carousel_box_get_n_pages: assertion 'HDY_IS_CAROUSEL_BOX (self)' failed
Dec  4 09:57:02 ZBOXID92ZBOXIQ012691b898 io.elementary.a[2144]: hdy_carousel_box_get_position: assertion 'HDY_IS_CAROUSEL_BOX (self)' failed
Dec  4 09:57:02 ZBOXID92ZBOXIQ012691b898 io.elementary.a[2144]: hdy_carousel_box_get_nth_child: assertion 'HDY_IS_CAROUSEL_BOX (self)' failed
Dec  4 09:57:02 ZBOXID92ZBOXIQ012691b898 io.elementary.a[2144]: hdy_carousel_box_scroll_to: assertion 'HDY_IS_CAROUSEL_BOX (self)' failed
Dec  4 09:57:07 ZBOXID92ZBOXIQ012691b898 io.elementary.a[2144]: hdy_carousel_box_get_position: assertion 'HDY_IS_CAROUSEL_BOX (self)' failed
Dec  4 09:57:07 ZBOXID92ZBOXIQ012691b898 io.elementary.a[2144]: hdy_carousel_box_get_n_pages: assertion 'HDY_IS_CAROUSEL_BOX (self)' failed
Dec  4 09:57:07 ZBOXID92ZBOXIQ012691b898 io.elementary.a[2144]: hdy_carousel_box_get_position: assertion 'HDY_IS_CAROUSEL_BOX (self)' failed
Dec  4 09:57:07 ZBOXID92ZBOXIQ012691b898 io.elementary.a[2144]: hdy_carousel_box_get_nth_child: assertion 'HDY_IS_CAROUSEL_BOX (self)' failed
Dec  4 09:57:07 ZBOXID92ZBOXIQ012691b898 io.elementary.a[2144]: hdy_carousel_box_scroll_to: assertion 'HDY_IS_CAROUSEL_BOX (self)' failed
Dec  4 09:57:12 ZBOXID92ZBOXIQ012691b898 io.elementary.a[2144]: hdy_carousel_box_get_position: assertion 'HDY_IS_CAROUSEL_BOX (self)' failed
Dec  4 09:57:12 ZBOXID92ZBOXIQ012691b898 io.elementary.a[2144]: hdy_carousel_box_get_n_pages: assertion 'HDY_IS_CAROUSEL_BOX (self)' failed
Dec  4 09:57:12 ZBOXID92ZBOXIQ012691b898 io.elementary.a[2144]: hdy_carousel_box_get_position: assertion 'HDY_IS_CAROUSEL_BOX (self)' failed
Dec  4 09:57:12 ZBOXID92ZBOXIQ012691b898 io.elementary.a[2144]: hdy_carousel_box_get_nth_child: assertion 'HDY_IS_CAROUSEL_BOX (self)' failed
Dec  4 09:57:12 ZBOXID92ZBOXIQ012691b898 io.elementary.a[2144]: hdy_carousel_box_scroll_to: assertion 'HDY_IS_CAROUSEL_BOX (self)' failed
Dec  4 09:57:13 ZBOXID92ZBOXIQ012691b898 gsd-color[1508]: failed to set screen _ICC_PROFILE: L’ouverture du fichier « /var/lib/lightdm/.local/share/icc/edid-1a22a3e94c53ede7c5c8ae97c02c4885.icc » a échoué : Permission non accordée
Dec  4 09:57:17 ZBOXID92ZBOXIQ012691b898 io.elementary.a[2144]: hdy_carousel_box_get_position: assertion 'HDY_IS_CAROUSEL_BOX (self)' failed
Dec  4 09:57:17 ZBOXID92ZBOXIQ012691b898 io.elementary.a[2144]: hdy_carousel_box_get_n_pages: assertion 'HDY_IS_CAROUSEL_BOX (self)' failed
Dec  4 09:57:17 ZBOXID92ZBOXIQ012691b898 io.elementary.a[2144]: hdy_carousel_box_get_position: assertion 'HDY_IS_CAROUSEL_BOX (self)' failed
Dec  4 09:57:17 ZBOXID92ZBOXIQ012691b898 io.elementary.a[2144]: hdy_carousel_box_get_nth_child: assertion 'HDY_IS_CAROUSEL_BOX (self)' failed
Dec  4 09:57:17 ZBOXID92ZBOXIQ012691b898 io.elementary.a[2144]: hdy_carousel_box_scroll_to: assertion 'HDY_IS_CAROUSEL_BOX (self)' failed
```

If you want to see more : https://pastebin.com/4Dwat7fz

Comment: There is not enough information here to begin to guess at the issue. Could you [edit] your question to include: (1) the brand and model of your computer (2) any error messages that you may see when the system locks up (3) logs from `/var/log/syslog` from around the time the system locks up. With this information, it may be possible to figure out why your machine is having trouble and offer a solution 

Answer (score 0):

I disables "suspend" to see if it is better :

> sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-> sleep.target